# Does Altair send data to an outside server?

Tags: python-3.x, altair

I am new to Altair and working on creating interactive graphs for my data. I was told by my mentor before starting the project that he thinks the data is being manipulated through outside server. Now the data that I am working on is highly confidential and needs to stay within the company.

Could anyone please help me understand if it really does send my data to an outside server, and if does is there anything I can do to work on it locally.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Altair does not send data to an outside server. All the data remains local to your Python process (and your Jupyter notebook process, if applicable).